# How to disable dash plugins?

Tags: unity, 14.10, unity-dash

How can i disable `Dash plugins` and `More suggestions` in the dash?
Here is a [screenshot.](http://s13.postimg.org/vypivzmgn/disable.png)

Answer (score 0):

An example - In your screen you show Banshee selected. Just single click on > on the next screen click the disable button to disable. Same for anything else in the `Dash plugins` section

Comment: That does not solve the problem.I found the solution for "More suggestions".In the Dash-->Filter Results-->Sources-->Local Apps.But as i discovered this is a temporary solution,every time that i reboot/log off the settings come back to default.